# How to resize the portion of geometry keeping other parts constant in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, mvvm, geometry

I am under a situation where i have to resize a geometry having path this

```
   viewModel.Shapes.Add(new ShapeDataModel
            {
                Type = "T-Type",
                Geometry = Geometry.Parse("M 0,0 H 600 V 200 H 375 V 600 H 225 V 200 H 0 V 0 Z"),  /path
                Width = 170, Height=300,

                //new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(200, 50, 50, 100)),
                Fill = Brushes.Yellow,
                Stroke = Brushes.DarkGreen,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Left=300,
                Top=200

            });
```

It is binded in View like this :

```
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}" 
                      Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                      Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                      StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

With this geometry   Geometry = Geometry.Parse("M 0,0 H 600 V 200 H 375 V 600 H 225 V 200 H 0 V 0 Z") . I get a T-shaped image using this geometry.

I am able to resize it. The problem is i just want to resize only one portion of this image (lets say it should just resize the part covered in red arrow direction only, dragging from the red circle at bottom in the direction of arrow). Lets say this top-right portion of T-Image like this http://prntscr.com/frzgqf keeping other 
part constant.

How to resize the portion of geometry keeping other parts constant ?

Answer (score 0):

As seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-multiple-subpaths-within-a-pathgeometry

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax

You could try break down the path M's to create a couple of inner paths which then you could work on seperatly.

Comment: thanks but did u understood the question ? User will dynamically resize the portion of image by dragging from that corner.

Comment: Yes, but define "Portion of image"? If you know before rendering that you got couple of image then what you really need to do is create a Canvas panel, and put all parts of the image as Paths that are children of the Canvas.